# A conjecture involving prime numbers and circles

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry, circles

Given the series of prime numbers greater than $9$, we organize them in four rows, according to their last digit ($1,3,7$ or $9$). The column in which they are displayed is the ten to which they belong, as illustrated in the following scheme.

[image]

My conjecture is:

> **Given any two primes (i.e. given any two points in the above scheme), it is always possible to find a circle passing through *at least* other two points, representing other two primes.**

Here I present some examples, taking two random points. Sorry for the bad quality of the picture.

[image]

Since I am not an expert of prime numbers, this can be an obvious result (if true, of course). In this case, I apologize for the trivial question.

However, I tried to attack the problem by means of the equation of the circle, but I got lost. Thanks for your help!

NOTE: You might be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2888522/559615) and in this [other](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889224/559615) post. Also, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889805/559615) I state a similar conjecture for ellipses.

Comment: Fascinating...brilliant question!

Comment: You should put a bounty on this question. I might do so myself if I can't figure it out

Comment: At first sight your conjecture is very beautiful. However it seems that, in order to make it plausible you must add some minimum "distance" between the two arbitrary primes when starting because a "little" distance could be such that any other prime is touch by the corresponding circle. (sorry for bad English)

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for your observation. However, the minimal distance is in unit of "1 ten" in the graph, and it seems to work for any of these couples.

Comment: My comment was wrong in its very base because there are infinitely many circles passing by two points no matter what near are.  Good luck.

Comment: @Piquito I see. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about the process by which you generated these circles? It might help me get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @LoganToll Sure: First I randomly choose 2 points, then I look for other 2 points from which a circle can pass. That's all. The point of the conjecture is that one can always find such circle, independently on the initial choice.

Comment: then a question immediately pops out: what happens if the representation is done in a base other than 10.

Comment: @GCab I also thought about it and I am working on it! : ) Nice question!

Comment: Have you found any examples where the four primes end differently ie the circle goes through one and only one prime from each strand?

Comment: @Karl Wonderful observation!!!! No, however!

Comment: My very limited geometry says that you should be able to construct a circle through any 3 points that aren't colinear. Perhaps we then are searching for constraints on the fourth point?

Comment: @Karl .... Yes: $223, 239, 241, 317$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Karl Sure, this is another way to express the conjecture, likely more elegant!

Comment: @Karl No,  I AM actually wrong! The four primes I mentioned they do not pass from the same circle!

Comment: If you pick two points on different horizontal lines, then the answer should be implied by some standard conjectures (we wish for two linear polynomials to be simultaneously prime). If you pick two points on the same horizontal line, then this becomes a Goldbach-type problem. I don't know what standard conjectures there are extending Goldbach, but my guess is that this is a harder case. EDIT: never mind the latter part, forgot the other two points can be on the same side of the circle

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for your observation. I am not really familiar with the conjectures/problem you mentioned. Can you expand a bit? Thanks again!

Comment: The problem that I see is that the placement of points is mathematically arbitrary.  For example, the placement of 19 and 29 bears no relation to the numbers 19 and 29, nor does it have any relation to the placement of 31.  While the number 31 is much closer to 29 than 19 is, the point 19 is much closer to 19 than 31 is.

Mathematically, this comes down to a formula based on int(n/10) and (n%10), and I don't see how that will lead to a circle formula other than through random chance.

Comment: [A023186](http://oeis.org/A023186)  -- two widely separated Isolated primes of different modulus likely provide an answer.   2179 and 31587561361 seems like a good candidate set.

Comment: @hymie It is an interesting observation. However, don't you think it could be only a matter of scaling? The same conjecture, according to your remark (if I understood it correctly), should be rephrased in terms of a _ellipse_ rather than to a _circle_, right?  What I don't get is your conclusion about the "chance". What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @EdPegg Thanks for your comment. Please, can you expand it a bit further? I am not sure to have understood! Thanks again!

Comment: @RushabhMehta Thanks for your appreciation!

Comment: I just randomly came across this and, I have to say, this is pretty neat!

Answer (score 10):

Assuming [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac's_conjecture) we will always be able to find two primes $(c,d)$ such that

$$
\left\lfloor{ \frac{a}{10}} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{b}{10}}\right\rfloor = -\left(\left\lfloor{\frac{c}{10}}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{\frac{d}{10}}\right\rfloor\right)
$$

(the distance between $a$ and $b$ along the $x$-axis is equal to the negative of the distance between $c$ and $d$) and

$$
a = b,\; \; c=d \; \mod 10
$$

($a$ and $b$, and $c$ and $d$, end in the same digits).

This defines an isosceles trapezium, which is always a cyclic quadrilateral (a quadrilateral such that a circle can be drawn with its 4 vertices.

If $a = b \mod 10 \;$, the above argument still probably holds, but I have not found a proof.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Just, I don't get the first point: I am not sure that the fact that the primes are infinite can ensure that your formula applies. Can you deepen this point? Thanks again!

Comment: It follows trivially from [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture), which is probably true, but otherwise, I can't find any obvious way to prove it. Much like Polignac's conjecture (a generalisation of the twin prime conjecture) it is likely easy to state, and incredibly difficult to prove.

Comment: You should edit your answer to make it clear that it is just a conjecture. The way it is currently written, it looks like you are claiming a proof.

Comment: TonyK - Clarified that it assumes Polignac's conjecture. I am claiming a proof, it is just dependent upon a different conjecture. Jyrki Lahtonen, good point, I didn't think through that properly, fixed.

Comment: If the two given primes are on the same horizontal line (i.e. are congruent mod 10), and if one of the primes is quite far to the left (the diagram does not continue to the left; if negative primes were included, things would be easier; the asker said primes greater than $7$), does your argument work? For example if one prime is $11$, at $(1,1)$, and the other prime is $131$, at $(13, 1)$, how can we proceed? I tried to find a "bad" example of this kind with a computer search but could not locate one. So maybe the conjecture is true for these cases also.

Comment: I missed that case, and I can't think of how to prove it. That said, it would not surprise me at all if the conjecture still held true, I just can't see why. Even if there are counterexamples, I would guess that there are finitely many. If I can think of a proof I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some loose intuition to convince you that it is equally hard as the twin prime conjecture. Especially, to convince you that there's no point in trying to prove or disprove it:

- At most as hard as the twin prime conjecture:
  Take two primes $p_1,p_2$. If the twin prime conjecture is true, it is reasonable to expect that, for any even $2k \geq 2$ and $n \bmod 10$ there are infinitely many prime pairs $(q_1,q_2)$ with $q_2-q_1 = 2k$ and $q_1 \equiv n \pmod{10}$.<sup>1</sup> Then for any given $p_1,p_2$ not congruent mod $10$ we can find two other primes to form a trapezium. This takes care of the case where $p_1,p_2$ are not congruent, at least.
- At least as hard as the twin prime conjecture:
  Four points with coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$ are concyclic iff 
  $$\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & y_1 & x_1^2 + y_1^2 \\
  1 & x_2 & y_2 & x_2^2 + y_2^2 \\
  1 & x_3 & y_3 & x_3^2 + y_3^2 \\
  1 & x_4 & y_4 & x_4^2 + y_4^2
  \end{vmatrix} = 0$$
  This gives, for every pair of primes $(p_1,p_2)$ a degree $4$ equation in two primes $q_1,q_2$ (and their residues mod $10$). Current methods are nowhere near proving that it has a solution; indeed, we cannot even show that the degree 1 (!) equation $$q_2-q_1-2k = 0$$ has a solution for every $k$.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although, there was an article that appeared a few years ago with some computations, suggesting that the distribution of the remainder of three consecutive primes mod a given integer, is not uniform. Anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Barto. Yes, I agree with you. Other answers too go in the same direction. However, I think it is interesting to see the Goldbach and the Twins conjectures somehow gathered in only one, if I haven't misunderstood the comments to this post. I am new to the study of prime numbers and my ideas can be really naive. I apologize in this case, and thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- It seems to me it is impossible to prove this geometrically. However, algebraically it could be maybe possible. The general equation of a circumference $\Gamma$ is $$x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ and the compatibility condition for four points $(p_1,0),(p_2,0),(p_3,k),(p_4,k)\space$in $\Gamma$ is

$$\det\begin{vmatrix}
p_1 & 0 & 1 & p_1^2 \\ 
p_2 & 0 & 1 & p_2^2  \\ 
p_3 & k & 1 & p_3^2+k^2  \\ 
p_4 & k & 1 & p_4^2 +k^2 \notag
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

In this case $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are primes, the two first points are in the x-axis and the other in the line $y=k\ne0$.

Puting, for example, $p_1=37$ and $p_2=47$, the choice of $(p_3,k)$ determine for $p_3$ fixed (say $23$) and $k$ as parameter a family of circumferences $\Gamma_k$ defined by a quadratic equation (cubic?) $$Q(p_4,k)=0$$ in which the arbitrary variation of $k$ could give a prime $p_4$ maybe.

Comment: I think your notation is different from OP's: OP designates primes by a tuple $(a,b)$ which represents the prime $10\times a+b$, and so $a$ and $b$ need not be primes. Also, on the $x$-axis there are no primes: it is divisible by $10$.

Comment: This is not properly the problem but a way of see how a circumference passing for three (arbitrary) points can have too another desirable point  according with manipulating  $p_4$ and $k$ in the quadratic $Q(p_4,k)=0$. (bad English, I know).

Comment: @Piquito It seems to me that the conjecture is true for any conic (i.e. given any 4 random primes, we can always find at least other 2 primes belonging to the same conic). Can you check this? Thanks for your interesting comments!

Comment: All depends of the corresponding $Q(p_4,k)$ above, I guess: fixing $p_4$ you do have freedom for $k$ so you plausibly can extend your conjecture (in case it is true).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a mathematician, so take everything here with a grain of salt.  I couldn't help but be interested though.

You can circumscribe a circle on any trapezoid.  Any two primes equivalent mod $10$ can form one base of a trapezoid; any two primes not equivalent mod $10$ can form the side of a trapezoid, including primes $10x+y_1$ and $10x+y_2$, which would form a rectangle, special case of a trapezoid.

I'm going to treat the second case first, as I think it's actually easier.  Let's take two random primes that have a difference of $10a-b$.  If we can two primes with a difference of $10(a-1)+b$, with the same $y$ coordinates, then we can form a trapezoid.  So this is basically equivalent to the conjecture that for every even $d$, there are primes $p>q$ for which $p-q=d$.  This is an open conjecture which, if I'm not mistaken, is true if both the Goldbach conjecture and the twin prime conjecture are true.

For the first case, in order to find a trapezoid, we need a second pair of primes whose average is within $\pm 4$ of the average of the first pair of primes.  So, can we find two primes with an arbitrary average? This *is* just the Goldbach conjecture: for any even $k$, there are primes $p, q $ for which $p+q =k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your observations. They look interesting. I am not a mathematician as well, so I have to study a bit more the conjectures you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: Thankfully those conjectures are easily understood!  In simple language, the Goldbach conjecture states that even even number is the sum of two (odd) prime numbers.  The twin prime conjecture states that there are infinitely many "twin primes," that is, pairs separated by 2, like 3 and 5 or 41 and 43.

Comment: I see. So, you mean that to prove my conjecture would imply to prove both the "Goldbach" and "Twins" ones, don't you?

Comment: I also realized there are a couple of types I've missed.  There are some rectangles that are tilted with respect to Cartesian coordinates, that produce circles from primes on all four lines.  The quartets (7, 29, 61, 83) and (13, 31, 79, 97) and (23, 59, 61, 97) are examples of those.  There will also be sets of two on a vertical line and two on a horizontal line that will form trapezoids, for instance (23, 29, 41, 101) and (13, 17, 31, 71). All of these cases rely on finding similar triangles though, so I think they'll be uncommon past the small numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "trapezoid"? Isosceles trapezia ($AB||DC$ and $AD=BC$) are cyclic but other trapezia are not.