# A conjecture involving prime numbers and parallelograms

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

As already introduced in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2886024/559615), given the series of prime numbers greater than $9$, let organize them in four rows, according to their last digit ($1,3,7$ or $9$). The column in which they are displayed is the ten to which they belong, as illustrated in the following scheme.

[image]

Within this scheme, and given the tens $N=0,3,6,9\ldots$, we can uniquely define a parallelogram by means of the four points corresponding to the four integers $N+1$, $(N+10)+1$, $(N+40)+9$ and $(N+50)+9$, as easily illustrated below.

[image]

For instance, the parallelogram corresponding to the ten $N=3$ is defined by the integers $31,41,79$ and $89$, whereas the one corresponding to $N=6$ is defined by $61,71,109, 119$.

My conjecture is:

> **On the perimeter of each parallelogram there cannot be more than $7$ primes.**

In the following picture, I denote with a red cross some of the *missing primes*, i.e. those integers that occupy one of the $8$ possible positions that the primes can occupy on the parallelograms, but that are *not* primes.

[image]

And here some more (sorry for the bad quality).

[image]

(This conjecture is motivated by the fact that, if true, it can perhaps be used to devise a method to determine which point will be missing on the parallelogram $N+1$, knowing which ones are missing on the previous $N$ parallelograms, but this is another problem!).

So far, I tried to use the strategies suggested in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2886024/559615), but without much success.

I apologize in case this is a trivial question, and I will thank you for any suggestion and/or comment. Also, in case this question is not clear or not rigorous, please help me to improve it (I am not an expert of prime numbers).  Thank you!

**EDIT:** A follow-up of this post can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889224/559615), where I try to use this conjecture in order to locate the "missing primes" on the parallelograms...

Comment: I think you will enjoy learning about [wheel](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/WheelFactorization.html) [factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

Comment: The person who downvoted this is an absolute swamp monster.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The eight points on each parallelogram cover all residues mod 7.

Comment: Thanks! Please, can you expand your answer a bit more? I am not very familiar with this topic, and I did not get the connection between your answer and the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andrea The point is that at least one of the eight numbers on any parallelogram is divisible by 7 and therefore not a prime number.

Comment: @MarcPaul Thank you. I got it now! But of course, this does not help to predict which points will be missing on the $N$-th parallelogram, if we know which ones are missing in the previous $N-1$ parallelograms, right?

Comment: ... or maybe yes? What about using the picture I added at the end of the question?

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto : you should ask another question if you have another precise request (this one was nice and fun, btw)

Comment: @Evargalo Sure, you're definitely right. I will do it, after having edited the pictures! : )

Answer (score 13):

This is an expansion of Michal's answer. We can find a multiple of 7 on each of the first seven parallelograms: 49, 77, 119, 91, 133, 161, 203.

Now every parallelogram can be obtained by taking one of these first seven parallelograms and adding 210 to each point. Since 210 is a multiple of 7, each point listed above will be translated onto missing points. This gives a way to compute a missing point on every parallelogram: if you find the remainder mod 210 of the points on the parallelogram, it must contain one of the seven values I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a closed formula for the missing points. These seem to be (conjeture, but should not be difficult to prove) the composite integers $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=\pm 1 \mod 6$. This sequence gives: 1,25,35,49,55,65,77,85,91,95,115,119,121...

Comment: Every positive integer, prime or composite (or 1!), is on one of the parallelograms if and only if it is congruent to $\pm 1 \mod 6$. The parallelograms were presumably constructed this way in the first place because except for 2 and 3, numbers with any other residues mod 6 will never be prime.