# Analysis of super-structures emerging in a spiral representation of prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, prime-numbers

The fact that each prime number (greater than $9$) ends with one of the four digits $1,3,7,9$, allows us to classify the tens in which the primes are found according to which of these four digits, added to the tens, yields to a prime number.

For example, for the first ten we have $1 \rightarrow \{1,3,7,9\}$. In fact, $10+1$, $10+3$, $10+7$ and $10+9$ are all primes. Conversely, for the twentieth ten the association reads $20 \rightarrow \{\}$, since there are no primes between $200$ and $209$.

It is easy to see that each ten is associated to one (and only one) group of symbols, chosen among the following $16$ distinct alternatives: $\{\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{7\}$, $\{9\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,7\}$, $\{1,9\}$,  $\{3,7\}$, $\{3,9\}$, $\{7,9\}$, $\{1,3,7\}$, $\{1,3,9\}$, $\{1,7,9\}$, $\{3,7,9\}$, $\{1,3,7,9\}$.

For the sake of simplicity, we can identify each of these $16$ distinct groups of symbols  with a *single* symbol, or with a single **color**, as illustrated below:

[image]

Each of these colors represents how many prime numbers there are in one ten (and *which* ones). In practice, we have just split the complexity of primes into tens and colors.

The color-code is of course arbitrary, and a better choice is possible. Here I chose a gradient that ranges from no primes at all in a ten (black) to all the four possible primes in a ten (white), intentionally avoiding fancier solutions (any suggestion is welcome!).

By means of this representation it is possible to build a discrete spiral (as suggested by Alex R. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896147/559615)) in which each tile represents one ten, and whose tiles color obeys the code illustrated before.

Here I show some examples until the ten 160, 360 and 640 (the number inside the tiles indicates here the related ten).

[image]

And here I present a more expanded example, until the ten 2250.

[image]

Finally, I present an excerpt of the upper part of the spiral ranging up to 25000 tens, *apparently* showing peculiar coiled, bundled super-structures, recalling fluid turbulence (click on the image to expand it).

[image]

(It would be great if someone could reproduce the same result with a different platform/code. See the NOTE at the bottom for technical details).

Now, the construction of the discrete spiral can be done, given a number of tens, also from outside to inside, as illustrated below

[image]

Let us compute the same spiral as before, up to 2250 tens:

[image]

And then let analyze a detail of the spiral related to 25000 tens:

[image]

Again, *it seems* that we find similar coiled super-structures as we have obtained for the spiral built starting from the center.

My question is:

> **How can we define/quantify the similarity of these two kinds of spirals? And, admitting that there is a similarity, where does it come from?**

And, in general, which techniques are used to study this kind of data? Can we treat them as stochastic/random matrices? I would say no, but I am not sure.

A related question (still a reference request) is if somebody knows whether such approach to the study of prime number was already attempted.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, here's the spiral of 2250 tens with **random values** for the tiles color-code (chosen among the 16 shades defined above):

[image]

and an extract of a 25000-tens spiral with random values:

[image]

Which brings us back to the open question.

Thanks for your comments and suggestions. Sorry for naivety, trivialities, and imprecision.

**NOTE:** The pictures are obtained with a combination of $\texttt{R}$, Xfig and bash. Prime numbers are calculated with the $\texttt{factorize}$ function, available within the $\texttt{R}$-package $\texttt{gmp}$.

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897580/559615), in which I introduce the same representation.

Comment: Have you, for comparison, tried generating a random string of these sixteen shades of gray and arranging them in a spiral. Does a simular turbulent pattern emerge?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales No, but it is a good idea. However, there are also other not-random structures (e.g. look at the left side of the second extract, there is like a straight line, unless it is an artifact). I will do it! Thanks!

Comment: It would bolster your case that this is not a random effect.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Done! I edited the post. To me, it seems the same as the primes-spiral (just a bit whiter, as it should). This actually reinforce the motivation of the question. How can we distinguish/analyze these two kinds of data sets?

Comment: Instead of a random string of gray shades, it might be better to look at a string where the probability of a gray shade is related to the number of primes (0 to 4) expected in the range of 10 integers using a rough estimate from the prime number theorem. That is, for the range $[10N..10N+9]$, choose a random variate from the binomial distribution for $4$ trials with probability of success $p=2.5/(\ln 10N)$, and then choose a random shade of gray for a set with that number of $1$s in it. [Quickly corrected $0.4$ to $2.5=1/0.4$.]

Comment: @SteveKass Great! I will do it! Thanks!

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto We tend to see a pattern even if there is none. And even if the first primes form a pattern , this pattern will amost surely eventually vanish , if we go to larger primes. Always remember : "Big primes (and numbers) are different!"